# jquery refreshing div shows div again

Tags: jquery, html, refresh

I am have a div that shows the result of a mysql query.  There are times that the database will have entries added or edited so I want to be able to refresh the div on the click of a button. It kind of works, but kind of does not.  Here is my code

```
<a id="refresh" href="#">click</a>

<script>
    $(function() {
      $("#refresh").click(function(evt) {
         $("#container").load("index.php")
         evt.preventDefault();
      })
    })
</script>
```

The first time I click the link it displays the WHOLE index.php inside the original container div.  Every click after that will refresh the newly created index.php like i want to, the only problem is that it shows the double index.php.  Can someone please point the probably obvious and hopefully simple mistake i am making?  thanks!

Comment: Does `index.php` have an element with a `container` ID?

Comment: yes it does, that is the one that i am trying to refresh

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting what is already inside the div before loading new data into it?

something like this

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $("#refresh").click(function(evt) {
         $("#container").html("");
         $("#container").load("index.php")
         evt.preventDefault();
      })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: unfortunately that did not work.  it cleared the div and then produced the same result